# Express.js and. Angular 7 - 3rd party cookie problem

Tags: angular, express, cookies, express-session

So I am utilising **express-session** to create a session to authenticate the user login in on the **Angular frontend** (They on different Domains), the problem I'm having in production is that if the user has **3rd party cookies** disabled on their browser the session doesn't persist and constantly logs them out. It works in development and I have CORS enabled with Credential set to true.

Comment: And where is your question? Thats the behaviour of disabling cookies. The only way arround is to setup a token based authentication saved in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. If the user has disabled coockies tell him via popup that he have to login every time.

Comment: I stated a problem but alas, I have found a solution to the problem so thanks though, I'll post an Answer soon for anyone that hits the same problem